# Java code that prints the customer name, discount level, the original purchase price, promotional price and the amount saved

Tags: java, if-statement

Over all, this code is supposed to ask for the customers name, member level, and original purchase price. It should store all of those in their respective variables, if something other than an accepted member level is entered the program is supposed to exit. After all the variables are stored, the customer's name, member level, original purchase price, promotional price, and amount saved should be printed out in the format at the end of this post. Also, could you tell me if my variables are named correctly and if the whole code is formatted properly. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Discount{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double purchase = 0.0;
        double platinum = (purchase * .2);
        double gold = (purchase * .15);
        double silver = (purchase * .1);
        String Platinum = null;
    String Gold = null;
    String Silver = null;
    String customerName = null;
    String level = null;
    double discount = 0.0;

    System.out.print("Please enter a customer name: ");
    customerName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the customer's member level: ");
    level = keyboard.nextLine();
```

This part is supposed to exit the program if anything other than Silver, Gold, or Platinum are printed; however, it will exit no matter what is typed in. If I leave this part out, it will proceed to ask how much the original purchase price but will not print any of the results.

```
          if (level != "Platinum" || level != "Gold" || level != "Silver")
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter the origianl purchase price: ");
    purchase = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (level.equals(Platinum) && purchase > 500)
    {
        discount = (platinum - (purchase*.05));
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 25% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Platinum))
    {
        discount = (platinum);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 20% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Gold))
    {
        discount = (gold);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 15% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Silver))
    {
        discount = (silver);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    /* Example:
            Congratulations, Marge Simpson!
    As a Silver level cardholder, you received a 10% discount during Bedlam.
    Original purchase price: $500.20
    Promotional price: $450.18
    Amount saved: $50.02 */
}
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed, was why do you have `System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);` for each case? The first and last 3 prints could (read should) all be done regardless of level, and should be outside any if statements.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin Can you dumb this down for me? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: I posted an answer to handle that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is not exiting when a wrong customer level is passed because the comparison checks are not right. You need to use `equals` method for string comparison here:

```
if (level != "Platinum" || level != "Gold" || level != "Silver")
```

change it to

```
if (!level.equals("Platinum") || !level.equals("Gold") || !level.equals("Silver"))
```

`!=` will not compare the string contents, rather it will check for objects equality.

**EDIT** From Willie answer I realized that you need to use && instead of || in your if check. So the correct condition should be:

```
if (!level.equals("Platinum") &&  !level.equals("Gold") && !level.equals("Silver"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it wouldn't work like that since the ones below had to use .equals() but I didn't know how to write it out. It still isn't printing out the results, do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @gdhc21 have u used && in your if check or ||?

Comment: @gdhc21 the check i have mentioned in my answer with && is correct. So what is happening? is your program not exiting when wrong level is entered?

Comment: It exits properly now, thanks for that, but it won't print the correct result at the end of the code. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Because explaining my comment would be almost impossible for my puny brain in another comment in the way I want to, here is an `answer` to your comment:

Part of your code is:

```
if (level.equals(Platinum) && purchase > 500)
    {
        discount = (platinum - (purchase*.05));
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 25% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Platinum))
    {
        discount = (platinum);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 20% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Gold))
    {
        discount = (gold);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 15% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
    else if (level.equals(Silver))
    {
        discount = (silver);
        System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.");
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
        System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
    }
```

And in this code you write out `System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");` once for every case and in each case they are identical. My suggestion is to write your code like this:

```
if (level != "Platinum" || level != "Gold" || level != "Silver")
{
    System.exit(0);
}

System.out.print("Please enter the origianl purchase price: ");
purchase = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");

if (level.equals(Platinum) && purchase > 500)
{
    discount = (platinum - (purchase*.05));
    System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 25% discount during Bedlam.");
}
else if (level.equals(Platinum))
{
    discount = (platinum);
    System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 20% discount during Bedlam.");
}
else if (level.equals(Gold))
{
    discount = (gold);
    System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 15% discount during Bedlam.");
}
else if (level.equals(Silver))
{
    discount = (silver);
    System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.");
}
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Origianl purchase price: $" + purchase);
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
```

Comment: I like that way better! Thanks!

Comment: It prints out this: Congratualations, Marge Simpson!
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at Discount.main(Discount.java:62)

Comment: I see why, I see your problem! lines like this: `else if (level.equals(Gold))` should be `else if (level.equals("Gold"))` That's why you didn't print before and why you get an error now.

Comment: As a Silver level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at Discount.main(Discount.java:62)